# docx4j cannot render margin properly

Tags: java, html, xhtml, docx, docx4j

I am using [docx4j-ImportXHTML](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML) to convert an XHTML into docx. When rendering to docx I am missing some style information.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Title of document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>This is <b>bold</b></p>
------------------------
<p style="margin-top:200px;margin-right:150px;margin-bottom:100px;margin-left:100px;">indent text</p>
------------------------
</body>

</html>
```

When running the above code, I do not see any top margin in the `docx` (left margin is there though). Also, if margins are defined as %, e.g., `margin-left:4%`, docx4j connot recognize it.

1. Is there anything else that I am missing or is this just docx4j limitation?
2. Is there any other better alternative in Java for converting `XHTML` to `docx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to add space around a paragraph, or page margins?

If you wanted page margins, you'd need paged media css to translate to w:sectPr/w:pgMargin

At the Flying Saucer end, see https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_36

I don't think we translate that instruction yet though.

Comment: I am trying to add space around the paragraph. I am converting an xhtml to docx. So if an xhtml code contains something like this <p> text1</p> <p style="margin-top:200px;> text2 </p>, then in the docx, there should be a 200px space between 'text1' and 'text2'. However, if I change the code <p style="margin-bottom:200px;> text1 </p> <p> text1</p> then I can see a 200px space between 'text1' and 'text2' in the docx. So it does respect "margin-bottom" attribute but not the "margin-top".

Comment: Thanks for this. Fixed by https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/7d334d8fe8f5f5f66ba3ba8e795f69c90d76382e

Comment: How can I get this fixed? I'm using maven dependency. Is there any build available that I can fetch via maven dependency?

Comment: It just missed the docx4j 8.1.3 release I'm afraid.  You can build it yourself of course, or wait for 8.1.4.

Comment: I have registered to the docx4j forum but my account is inactive for over a week. Do you happen to know how to activate it? It says I should contact to the board but I don't find any contact email.

Comment: I have activated it for you

Comment: Any suggestion where can I take a look for a workaround about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58044805/docx4j-cannot-render-text-indent