# docx4j cannot render <text-indent>

Tags: html, xhtml, docx, docx4j, wordml

I am using [docx4j-ImportXHTML](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML) to convert an XHTML into a docx. When rendering to docx I notice it doesn't render CSS `text-indent` property.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Title of document</title>
</head>

<body>

<p style="text-indent:100px;">indent text</p>

</body>

</html>
```

When running above code I do not see any indentation of the first line of the paragraph. However, while converting docx to xhtml it does interpret the first-line indent. Is there anything else that I am missing or is this just docx4j limitation? Is this a Flying Saucer's limitation?

Comment: Any suggestion where can I take a look for a workaround @JasonPlutext